# Lower elements in list given a certain position

Tags: python

I must lower letters in a list if the occupy a certain position given in a previous function I did. The function I must program is `lower_words`.

I'm having an issue: every time I lower an element the row is repeated.

I don't need to use the list "words" for this. Just left it there so you could understand better what the function does/must do. Can someone help me?

```
words= ["PATO", "GATO", "BOI", "CAO"]

grid1= ["PIGATOS", 
       "ANRBKFD", 
       "TMCAOXA", 
       "OOBBYQU", 
       "MACOUIV", 
       "EEJMIWL"]

 positions_words_occupy = ((0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 0), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (0, 5), (3, 2), (4, 3), (5, 4), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4)) #these are the positions the words occupy. I have determined these positions with a previous function. first is the line, second the column  


def lower_words(grid, positions_words_occupy):

    new= []

    for position in positions_words_occupy:

        line= position[0]
        column= position[1]

        row= grid[line]
        element= row[column]

        new.append(row.replace(element, element.lower()))

    return new
```

Expected output:

```
['pIgatoS', 'aNRBKFD', 'tMcaoXA', 'oObBYQU', 'MACoUIV', 'EEJMiWL']
```

Actual output:

```
['pIGATOS', 'aNRBKFD', 'tMCAOXA', 'ooBBYQU', 'PIgATOS', 'PIGaTOS', 'PIGAtOS', 'PIGAToS', 'OObbYQU', 'MACoUIV', 'EEJMiWL', 'TMcAOXA', 'TMCaOXa', 'TMCAoXA']
```

Changing the perspective, you can see it lowers the words I have in the list words:

```
 ['pIgatoS', 
  'aNRBKFD', 
  'tMcaoXA', 
  'oObBYQU', 
  'MACoUIV', 
  'EEJMiWL']
```

Comment: It is unclear what's the logic of this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very close! You're actually appending to your new list `new` every time you replace a letter. That is why you are getting so many values in your list.

Another way you would run your code is to create a copy of grid1, and then replace each word every time you replace a letter. Here is a new function implementing these small changes:

```
def lower_words(grid, positions_words_occupy):

    new = grid1.copy()

    for position in positions_words_occupy:

        line= position[0]
        column= position[1]

        row= new[line]
        element= row[column]

        #new.remove(row)
        new_word = row[:column] + element.lower() + row[column+1:]
        new[line] = new_word

    return new
```

Output running `lower_words(grid1, positions_words_occupy)`:

```
['pIgatoS', 'aNRBKFD', 'tMcaoXa', 'oObBYQU', 'MACoUIV', 'EEJMiWL']
```

Comment: 'oobbYQU' must be 'oObBYQU' :o

Comment: Worked! Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

I would first collect your grid positions in a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) or sets, then rebuild the strings with lowercase letters if their positions exist in these sets.

**Demo:**

```
from collections import defaultdict

grid1 = ["PIGATOS", "ANRBKFD", "TMCAOXA", "OOBBYQU", "MACOUIV", "EEJMIWL"]

positions_words_occupy = (
    (0, 0),
    (1, 0),
    (2, 0),
    (3, 0),
    (0, 2),
    (0, 3),
    (0, 4),
    (0, 5),
    (3, 2),
    (4, 3),
    (5, 4),
    (2, 2),
    (2, 3),
    (2, 4),
)

d = defaultdict(set)
for grid, pos in positions_words_occupy:
    d[grid].add(pos)

result = []
for grid, pos in d.items():
    result.append(
        "".join(x.lower() if i in pos else x for i, x in enumerate(grid1[grid]))
    )

print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
['pIgatoS', 'aNRBKFD', 'tMcaoXA', 'oObBYQU', 'MACoUIV', 'EEJMiWL']
```